# Strange ClassCastException when using ActiveRecord from Java

Tags: java, activerecord, jruby

I'm trying to use ActiveRecord from Java via JRuby, but facing "ClassCastExcecption" problem.

The sample application is implemented as follows:

example/User.java

```
package example;

public interface User {
    String getName();
}
```

example/UserManager.java

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserManager {
    List<User> all_users();
    User new_user(String name);
}
```

user_manager.rb (somewhere in the classpath)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'arjdbc'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Java::example.User
end

class UserManager
  include Java::example.UserManager

  def initialize
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter => "jdbcsqlite3",
      :database => "test.db"
    )
  end

  def new_user(name)
    User.new(:name => name)
  end

  def all_users
    User.all
  end
end

UserManager.new
```

example/Main.java

```
package example;

import org.jruby.embed.PathType;
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        container.setHomeDirectory("D:/bin/jruby-1.5.6"); // JRuby path

        Object userManagerObj = container.runScriptlet(
                PathType.CLASSPATH, "user_manager.rb");
        UserManager userManager = container.getInstance(
                userManagerObj, UserManager.class);

        userManager.new_user("Jane Doe");  // (A)

        System.out.println("Users:");
        for (User user : userManager.all_users()) {
            System.out.println(user.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

'Users' table is set up beforehand as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :users, :force => true do |t|
    t.column :name, :string
  end
end

User.create(:name => 'John Doe')
```

When I run the main class above, everything is fine.

```
Users:
John Doe
```

But, strangely, if I comment the line (A) out of Main.java, I get a ClassCastException.

```
Users:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyObject cannot be cast to example.User
    at example.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Also get a ClassCastException if I update the 'new_user' method to equivalent code using Class#allocate as follows:

```
u = User.allocate
u.send :initialize, {:name => name}
u
```

Why Class#new must be called in advance to avoid ClassCastException? Am I missing something?

I'm using JRuby 1.5.6. Gems:

- activerecord 3.0.3
- activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.1.0
- activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered: http://javalite.io/ ?

cheers